# Change value for specific objects in array

Tags: javascript

How can I change the status property to false of each entry with let's say group "B", without changing the others?
Either by mutating the array or returning a new one

```
const personnel = [
  { id: 0, name: "Audrey Holcomb", group: "A", status: true },
  { id: 1, name: "Gwendolyn Heath", group: "B", status: true },
  { id: 2, name: "Rivas Mclean", group: "C", status: true },
  { id: 3, name: "Valeria Schneider", group: "A", status: true },
  { id: 4, name: "Leticia Keith", group: "C", status: true },
  { id: 5, name: "Nadine Woodward", group: "B", status: true },
  { id: 6, name: "Shaffer Oliver", group: "A", status: true },
  { id: 7, name: "Meghan Norman", group: "B", status: true },
  { id: 8, name: "Kyle Smith", group: "C", status: true },
]
```

My initial approach was to forEach the entries that had the specific group parameter I was looking for, but I didn't know how to single them out from the others.

```
personnel.forEach((p) => if(p.group === 'B') ) // ?
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use map to return a new array and modify the Group B elements as you go.  This method doesn't have anything to recommend it over forEach in this particular instance, I don't think, but in more complicated circumstances it can be much simpler.

```js
const personnel = [
  {id: 0, name: 'Audrey Holcomb', group: 'A', status: true},
  {id: 1, name: 'Gwendolyn Heath', group: 'B', status: true},
  {id: 2, name: 'Rivas Mclean', group: 'C', status: true},
  {id: 3, name: 'Valeria Schneider', group: 'A', status: true},
  {id: 4, name: 'Leticia Keith', group: 'C', status: true},
  {id: 5, name: 'Nadine Woodward', group: 'B', status: true},
  {id: 6, name: 'Shaffer Oliver', group: 'A', status: true},
  {id: 7, name: 'Meghan Norman', group: 'B', status: true},
  {id: 8, name: 'Kyle Smith', group: 'C', status: true},
];

let changed = personnel.map(m=>{
  m.status = m.group == 'B' ? false : m.status;
  return m;
});

console.log(changed);
```

You might also create an arrow function to make things a little cleaner, and then since you are only using one line in map, you can omit `return` and the curly braces:

```js
const personnel = [
  {id: 0, name: 'Audrey Holcomb', group: 'A', status: true},
  {id: 1, name: 'Gwendolyn Heath', group: 'B', status: true},
  {id: 2, name: 'Rivas Mclean', group: 'C', status: true},
  {id: 3, name: 'Valeria Schneider', group: 'A', status: true},
  {id: 4, name: 'Leticia Keith', group: 'C', status: true},
  {id: 5, name: 'Nadine Woodward', group: 'B', status: true},
  {id: 6, name: 'Shaffer Oliver', group: 'A', status: true},
  {id: 7, name: 'Meghan Norman', group: 'B', status: true},
  {id: 8, name: 'Kyle Smith', group: 'C', status: true},
];
const checkGroup=(a)=>{
  a.status = a.group=='B' ? false : a.status;
  return a;
};    

let changed = personnel.map(m=>checkGroup(m));

console.log(changed);
```

For a little more extensibility, you can set up the helper function take an argument, say the target you want to change:

```js
const personnel = [
  {id: 0, name: 'Audrey Holcomb', group: 'A', status: true},
  {id: 1, name: 'Gwendolyn Heath', group: 'B', status: true},
  {id: 2, name: 'Rivas Mclean', group: 'C', status: true},
  {id: 3, name: 'Valeria Schneider', group: 'A', status: true},
  {id: 4, name: 'Leticia Keith', group: 'C', status: true},
  {id: 5, name: 'Nadine Woodward', group: 'B', status: true},
  {id: 6, name: 'Shaffer Oliver', group: 'A', status: true},
  {id: 7, name: 'Meghan Norman', group: 'B', status: true},
  {id: 8, name: 'Kyle Smith', group: 'C', status: true},
];
const checkGroup=(a,b)=>{
  a.status = a.group==b ? false : a.status;
  return a;
};    

let changed = personnel.map(m=>checkGroup(m, 'B'));

console.log(changed);
```

And you might also tighten up that boolean logic to avoid the ternary operator, although in this particular case it will probably be harder to read and maintain than the other way, and it's only marginally shorter:

```js
const personnel = [
  {id: 0, name: 'Audrey Holcomb', group: 'A', status: true},
  {id: 1, name: 'Gwendolyn Heath', group: 'B', status: true},
  {id: 2, name: 'Rivas Mclean', group: 'C', status: true},
  {id: 3, name: 'Valeria Schneider', group: 'A', status: true},
  {id: 4, name: 'Leticia Keith', group: 'C', status: true},
  {id: 5, name: 'Nadine Woodward', group: 'B', status: true},
  {id: 6, name: 'Shaffer Oliver', group: 'A', status: true},
  {id: 7, name: 'Meghan Norman', group: 'B', status: true},
  {id: 8, name: 'Kyle Smith', group: 'C', status: true},
];
const checkGroup=(a,b)=>{
  a.status = !(a.group==b || !a.status)
  return a;
};    

let changed = personnel.map(m=>checkGroup(m, 'B'));

console.log(changed);
```

But if your use case is really as simple as what you're describing, then you're going be hard pressed to beat forEach, which you can accomplish in one line:

```js
const personnel = [
  {id: 0, name: 'Audrey Holcomb', group: 'A', status: true},
  {id: 1, name: 'Gwendolyn Heath', group: 'B', status: true},
  {id: 2, name: 'Rivas Mclean', group: 'C', status: true},
  {id: 3, name: 'Valeria Schneider', group: 'A', status: true},
  {id: 4, name: 'Leticia Keith', group: 'C', status: true},
  {id: 5, name: 'Nadine Woodward', group: 'B', status: true},
  {id: 6, name: 'Shaffer Oliver', group: 'A', status: true},
  {id: 7, name: 'Meghan Norman', group: 'B', status: true},
  {id: 8, name: 'Kyle Smith', group: 'C', status: true},
];

personnel.forEach(m=>{m.status = m.group == 'B' ? false : m.status});

console.log(personnel);
```

Another one line possibility is to use while with find to loop as long as the array contains an object where the group is B and the status is not false:

```js
const personnel = [
  {id: 0, name: 'Audrey Holcomb', group: 'A', status: true},
  {id: 1, name: 'Gwendolyn Heath', group: 'B', status: true},
  {id: 2, name: 'Rivas Mclean', group: 'C', status: true},
  {id: 3, name: 'Valeria Schneider', group: 'A', status: true},
  {id: 4, name: 'Leticia Keith', group: 'C', status: true},
  {id: 5, name: 'Nadine Woodward', group: 'B', status: true},
  {id: 6, name: 'Shaffer Oliver', group: 'A', status: true},
  {id: 7, name: 'Meghan Norman', group: 'B', status: true},
  {id: 8, name: 'Kyle Smith', group: 'C', status: true},
];

while(o = personnel.find(f=>f.group=='B'&&f.status)) { o.status = false; }

console.log(personnel);

let c = personnel.length;
while((o = personnel.find(f=>f.group=='B'&&f.status)) && c-->0) { o.status = false; }

console.log(personnel);
```

Be aware that this can set you up with a non-terminating loop if you aren't careful and hang the whole code.  It's good to put some failsafe condition in, for instance a counter that increments once per loop, and exit if you hit that condition.  In the second variant of the while solution, I set c to personnel.length and decrement each loop, exiting once c drops below 0.

And don't forget the venerable and vanilla `for` loop:

```js
const personnel = [
  {id: 0, name: 'Audrey Holcomb', group: 'A', status: true},
  {id: 1, name: 'Gwendolyn Heath', group: 'B', status: true},
  {id: 2, name: 'Rivas Mclean', group: 'C', status: true},
  {id: 3, name: 'Valeria Schneider', group: 'A', status: true},
  {id: 4, name: 'Leticia Keith', group: 'C', status: true},
  {id: 5, name: 'Nadine Woodward', group: 'B', status: true},
  {id: 6, name: 'Shaffer Oliver', group: 'A', status: true},
  {id: 7, name: 'Meghan Norman', group: 'B', status: true},
  {id: 8, name: 'Kyle Smith', group: 'C', status: true},
];

for(i=0; i<personnel.length; i++) {
  personnel[i].status = 
personnel[i].group == 'B' ? 
false : 
personnel[i].status
  ;
}

console.log(personnel);
```

Now, don't sleep on those last two.  They might not get a lot of love these EC6 days, but they will drastically outperform map, reduce, forEach, Object.keys(), etc.  That usually isn't an issue, so it's probably better to code whatever is the easiest to read, maintain and extend, but it is good to be aware that those methods come with performance costs.

Comment: Thanks for your extensive answer! I appreciate you putting this in perspective

Comment: YW.  Siva's answer is strong too.  The use of spread is non-intuitive there, but it does illustrate some good concepts.  Also, I don't think of this as a free coding service ;) especially on a question like this.  If you were asking something like this you probably just didn't know exactly how to ask (or you would have been able to google the answer).  In that case I think it's helpful to go over some core concepts and examples of different ways that you might approach the problem.  I was actually sitting here contemplating a couple of other methods.  If I can get them I'll add them.

Comment: That's the thing, I had no idea how to find an explanation. Results on google for searches like "change all entries with specific property in array of objects javascript" were all mismatched, usually concerning one entry with a unique value. So thanks again for your understanding.

Comment: Sure, when I first started I came in from having majored in music and hobby computering, so I had no CS background, so I didn't have a clue what anything was called, so it was very difficult to google an answer because I didn't know how to ask the question.  It took about a year after I started doing this full time to mostly figure out what things are called and how to ask so somebody else can answer.

Answer (score 2):

Loop through array, check if group is B and then change status to false

```js
const personnel = [
  { id: 0, name: "Audrey Holcomb", group: "A", status: true },
  { id: 1, name: "Gwendolyn Heath", group: "B", status: true },
  { id: 2, name: "Rivas Mclean", group: "C", status: true },
  { id: 3, name: "Valeria Schneider", group: "A", status: true },
  { id: 4, name: "Leticia Keith", group: "C", status: true },
  { id: 5, name: "Nadine Woodward", group: "B", status: true },
  { id: 6, name: "Shaffer Oliver", group: "A", status: true },
  { id: 7, name: "Meghan Norman", group: "B", status: true },
  { id: 8, name: "Kyle Smith", group: "C", status: true },
];

for (let i = 0; i < personnel.length; i++) {
  if (personnel[i]["group"] == "B") {
    personnel[i]["status"] = false;
  }
}

console.log(personnel);
```

Comment: You should make your code runnable...

Answer (score 2):

Use `map` and check for group

```js
const update = (arr, group = "B", status = false) =>
  arr.map((item) => ({
    ...item,
    status: item.group === group ? status : item.status,
  }));

const personnel = [
  { id: 0, name: "Audrey Holcomb", group: "A", status: true },
  { id: 1, name: "Gwendolyn Heath", group: "B", status: true },
  { id: 2, name: "Rivas Mclean", group: "C", status: true },
  { id: 3, name: "Valeria Schneider", group: "A", status: true },
  { id: 4, name: "Leticia Keith", group: "C", status: true },
  { id: 5, name: "Nadine Woodward", group: "B", status: true },
  { id: 6, name: "Shaffer Oliver", group: "A", status: true },
  { id: 7, name: "Meghan Norman", group: "B", status: true },
  { id: 8, name: "Kyle Smith", group: "C", status: true },
];

console.log(update(personnel))

console.log(update(personnel, "C", false))
```

Comment: I like the use of default arguments for extra extensibility.  Is the spread just to keep it all on one line?

Answer (score 0):

You can map through each item of your personnel list and check each object's group property. If it is equal to group "B", change the status to "false".

```
        personnel.map(item => {
          if (item?.group === 'B') {
            item.status = false;
          }
        });
```

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer such that others can learn from it